# How to check empty elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I initialised a vecotor of size 10 and I insert only 1 element and I want to check how many are not inserted. I have currently something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class VectorCheck 
{

private:

    vector<char> myVector;
    int size;
    int PosOfLastElement = 0;

public:

VectorCheck(int Vectorsize):
size(Vectorsize), myVector(Vectorsize)
{

}


int count()
{
    int numOfElements = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<myVector.size();i++)
    {
        if(myVector[i] == ' ')
        {
            numOfElements ++;
        }
    }

    cout << numOfElements << endl;

}

void addElement(char element)
{
    for(int i=PosOfLastElement; i<myVector.size();i++)
    {
        if(myVector[i]= ' ')
        {
            myVector[i] = element;
            PosOfLastElement = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}



};

int main()
{
    VectorCheck vectorTest(10);
    vectorTest.addElement('a');
    vectorTest.count();
}
```

my count function shows that there are 0 empty spaces but it should be 9. and I even tries to check something like this `if(myVector[i] == nullptr)` and it didn't compile. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Take a look at `std::vector<T>::capacity`

Comment: @Fureeish I checked and tried. It dispalys 10 ( which is the size of the vector )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your `count()` function returns `0` is because none of your elements in the vector are spaces `' '`. For this to work, fill your vector with spaces when you construct it:

```
VectorCheck(int Vectorsize):
size(Vectorsize), myVector(Vectorsize, ' ') // <-- Add ' ' here to fill the vector
{

}
```

Otherwise it will default to inserting `'\0'`s. The other option is to replace your check `== ' '` in `count()` with `== '\0'`. Incidentally, your `addElement()` function suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I didn't know about `myVector(Vectorsize, ' ')`

Comment: It turned out that the `myVector(Vectorsize, ' ')` is what I am looking for. Thanks again. It works like a champ

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the default value of elements of `vector<char>` would be `'\0'`, not `' '`. (Also note that you can always specify it by the 2nd parameter of the [constructor of `vector` (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).)

Secondly, `==` should be used instead of `=` for `if(myVector[i]= ' ')` in `addElement()`.

i.e.

```
int count()
{
    int numOfElements = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myVector[i] == '\0')
        {
            numOfElements ++;
        }
    }

    cout << numOfElements << endl;
    return numOfElements;
}

void addElement(char element)
{
    for(int i=PosOfLastElement; i<myVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myVector[i] == '\0')
        {
            myVector[i] = element;
            PosOfLastElement = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/AKKTFU54358)

Comment: Your element is _not_ being added because you are looking for `' '` when you should be looking for `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are initialising your `std::vector` with a size of 10, you are actually initialising those values to `'\0'`, but you're assuming they are being constructed with the space character.

You could change your constructor to have `myVector(VectorSize, ' ')` to fill it with space characters initially.  But, I think you're misusing vector.

If you want to pre-allocate a certain amount of space in the vector, use `reserve(10)` instead, and then just add items with `push_back()`.  Then `myVector.size()` will show the number of items in the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class VectorCheck 
{
private:
    vector<char> myVector;

public:
    VectorCheck(int initialCapacity)
    {
        myVector.reserve(initialCapacity);
    }

    size_t count()
    {
        return myVector.size();
    }

    void addElement(char element)
    {
        myVector.push_back(element);
    }
};

int main()
{
    VectorCheck vectorTest(10);
    vectorTest.addElement('a');
    cout << vectorTest.count() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Really? I'll update the answer when I'm back at a computer. Thx.